# Alternatives to combination to paste and parse functions using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'm trying to construct a general function to generate some graphics. So I have to create an axis label that combines an expression and a string. I've tried:

```
i <- 2
measure <- c(expression((kg/m^2)), "(%)")
variable <- c("BMI", "Cintilografia 1h")
data <- data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)
gp <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = parse(text = paste(variable[i], measure[i])))
```

It works for `i = 1`, but for `i = 2`.

I discovered parse function has some problems with special characters. I would prefer that the user-function does not to worry about these features. Then, I'm looking for a more general solution.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to paste and parse isn't a great idea when working with labels where you want to use `?plotmath` markup. It's better to work with expressions. The `bquote()` function makes it somewhat easier to pop in values into expressions. This should work for you

```
i<-1
g1<-ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = bquote(.(variable[i])~.(measure[[i]])))
i<-2
g2<-ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = bquote(.(variable[i])~.(measure[[i]])))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1,g2, ncol=2)
```

Also note that when using `bquote()` on the `measure` object, since it's an expression, you want to extract the sub-expressions with `[[ ]]` rather than `[ ]` because the latter always wraps the result in an `expression()` and `plotmath` doesn't like nested expressions -- you want proper call objects.

[image]